# Issues related to method split

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, split

I am developing a rails app. I want to split the sentence typed in a searchbox in my app using split(" "). But I am getting undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass error. I am using form data and since the form search box data is empty during page loading,I am getting this error.

My code is:-

```
def string_array_conversion(sentence)
 sen_array=Array.new
 values = sentence.split()

 values.each do |value|
  sen_array.push(value)
  puts value
 end
 puts "this is the array"
 puts sen_array
 return sen_array
end
```

Here the function parameter 'sentence' is a form data. It is in the caller method :params[pt]

The code that is calling the method is:

```
def new

@emp=Employee.new
@emps=Employee.all

@aut=Autocomp.new
@auts=Autocomp.all

@check=params[:pt]
puts @check

ret_sen_array=string_array_conversion(@check)
puts ret_sen_array
end
```

Please tell me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Check the answer below and tell me if it works or not?

Comment: You can use only `sentence.to_s.split()`. This will return array, you dont need to conver this array to another array ;)

Comment: thanks,,it seems a great solution for me @LukasBalik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
values = sentence.split()
```

Replace above line to following line.

```
values = if sentence.present?
  sentence.split()
else
  []
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`sentence` arrives `nil` into your method. We need the code that calls `string_array_conversion`

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is value of `sentence` is `nil`. Make sure the value of `sentence` is not `nil`. You can control the exception like this,

```
def string_array_conversion(sentence)
 return unless sentence

 sen_array=Array.new
 values = sentence.split()

 values.each do |value|
  sen_array.push(value)
  puts value
 end
 puts "this is the array"
 puts sen_array
 return sen_array
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take another approach to solve this problem.

In Ruby, `nil` responds to the method [`.to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/NilClass.html#method-i-to_s) and returns an empty string (`""`). In addition, a string can respond to this method and returns the same string (it's an idempotent operation). So, I'll call the method `.to_s` of the `sentence` variable to ensure working with strings:

```
    def string_array_conversion(sentence)
     sen_array=Array.new
     values = sentence.to_s.split()

     values.each do |value|
      sen_array.push(value)
      puts value
     end
     puts "this is the array"
     puts sen_array
     return sen_array
    end
```